# how do I fix a wrong UUID in grub.cfg?

Tags: linux, grub, uuid

I run Debian Wheezy alone on my PC and I recently copied the root partition to another with **rsync** as I found that worked well (I also know about dd and ddrescue but they leave unusable space on the new partition). I generated a new random UUID for the new partition with *sudo tune2fs -U random /dev/hda9* and also updated fstab / and /home entries.

Then as I know so little about GRUB I used a gui (GRUB Customizer) to probe for the new OS and add an entry to GRUB and the MBR -it makes an /etc/grub.d entry then updates GRUB.

On startup, the GRUB list contains the new OS (on sda9) but it boots the first OS (which I copied from -sda5).

/boot/grub/grub.cfg contains the new debian OS but it looks like this

```
set root='(hd0,msdos9)'  
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 64662470-0e58-4dfd-90ac-43227d773556  
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=cc3bca0d-aee4-4b9c-95c2-57212cc36d4d ro quiet  
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-2-amd64
```

the 1st uuid is of sda9, but the 2nd uuid there is of sda5.  I can change the 2nd uuid at startup (with E) and it boots sda9.
So how can I get grub.cfg corrected so that the sda9 GRUB list entry boots from sda9 permanently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg/` and replace sda5's UUID with sda9's:

```
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 64662470-0e58-4dfd-90ac-43227d773556  
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64 root=UUID=64662470-0e58-4dfd-90ac-43227d773556
```

To avoid this type of error in the future run `update-grub` *from the system you want to be using*. If you run it from the old OS, it will pick up the *current* root partition and set grub.cfg to boot from that.

Comment: and if I edit grub.cfg what will stop the 2nd uuid reverting to what it was before when a GRUB update is made? (as I know it will, I tried that)

Comment: @mozerella, Did you run update-grub from the sda9 system or the sda5?

Comment: from sda5, actually

Comment: @mozerella, try running it again but when you have booted into the sda9 OS.

Comment: I've just realised!  the OS on sda9 has its own grub.cfg file, so I needed to run update-grub from the OS on sda9. so thanks for pointing that out, shall I answer the Q?

Comment: @mozerella I was under the impression that I just did :), I'll update mine if that's OK.

Comment: just to point out, I am using both systems - I am not obsoleting the old one (which is main).

Comment: I'm a bit confused; so the grub.cfg on your sda5 partition is still wrong? But it doesn't matter as long as the one on sda9 is correct? Which one is Grub actually using?

Comment: I am having the same problem. In my case the faulty entries are created by 30_os_prober. In two entries the --set=root and the actual root which is passed to the image are swapped. In fact there should not be any UUIDs passed to the kernel at all as I have GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true set, but this does not seem to affect the os_prober. 

All this mess, just to write a config file. I guess I will disable 10_linux and 30_os_prober and just write my config in 40_custom. There is too much magic and it doesn't make things easier

Comment: +1 for confirming what I found out today and affirming I'm not crazy (in this case at least). Now I just need code set `linux` UUID to what `search` UUID is.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `update-grub` from `sda5` it reads the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` from `sda9` which was copied from `sda5`. First boot into `sda5` which is your primary OS. Then use these commands to fix:

```
SourceUUID=cc3bca0d-aee4-4b9c-95c2-57212cc36d4d
TargetUUID=64662470-0e58-4dfd-90ac-43227d773556
sudo mkdir /mnt/clone
sudo mount -t auto -v /dev/sda9 /mnt/clone
sudo sed -i "s/$SourceUUID/$TargetUUID/g" /mnt/clone/boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo update-grub
sudo umount /mnt/clone -l
```

I based this answer on a [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS clone to new partition script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605).

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove /boot/grub/menu.lst (you should cp a backup first) and then update-grub saying yes to generating a new one. It then detected the correct partition UUID to boot from.